#  Fill MySQL table with 2-dim array data

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fill MySQL table with 2-dim array data:

```
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($arr); $i++)
    {
    $query1="INSERT INTO `fsTest` (`id`,`xxx`,`yyy`,`zzz`)  
        VALUES('$arr[$i][0]','$arr[$i][1]','$arr[$i][2]','$arr[$i][3]');";
    $result1=DatabaseConnector::ExecuteQuery($query1);
    }
```

When I check the table 'fsTest' I can see just 1 line with the following entries [0] [1] [2] [3]. 
How to solve this issue?

UPDATE: Another thing is that I use $arr[$i][] = $val; to populate the array. var_dump($arr) returns Arrayint(0).

Comment: For one thing... You're not actually writing anything to the database in that loop.

Comment: @andrewsi I just skept this parto fo code, because it's working fine with other data structures

Comment: I may be mistaken, but shouldn't you serialize the 2-dimensional array before inserting? The array isn't a string.

Comment: try ...`VALUES('{$arr[$i][0]}','{$arr[$i][1]}',`...

Comment: Another problem is that I use $arr[$i][] =  $val; to populate the array. var_dump($arr) returns Arrayint(0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need curly braces around your variable names:

```
$query1 = "
    INSERT INTO `fsTest` (`id`,`xxx`,`yyy`,`zzz`)  
        VALUES('{$arr[$i][0]}','{$arr[$i][1]}','{$arr[$i][2]}','{$arr[$i][3]}');
";
```

Otherwise, the parser is lazy and will find `$arr[$i]` first and attempt to insert that value as a string, instead of `$arr[$i][0]`.

A quick example demonstrates this behavior:

```
$array = array( array( 'value'));
echo "$array[0][0]"; // Fails, Array to string conversion
echo "{$array[0][0]}"; // Prints value
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($arr); $i++)
{
$query1="INSERT INTO `fsTest` (`id`,`xxx`,`yyy`,`zzz`)  
    VALUES('".$arr[$i][0]."','".$arr[$i][1]."','".$arr[$i][2]."','".$arr[$i][3]."');";
$result1=DatabaseConnector::ExecuteQuery($query1);
}
```

Comment: I use $arr[$i][] = $val; to populate the array and var_dump($arr) returns Arrayint(0).